# Installing PHP APC on Windows/Apache

Tags: php, apache-http-server

i need help installing and configuring PHP APC i have downloaded from http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ in my PHP info, i see

Compiler    MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
Architecture    x86

so i downloaded [php_apc-5.3-nts-svn20100226-vc9-x86.zip](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_apc-5.3-nts-svn20100226-vc9-x86.zip). then to install, i tried adding

```
[PHP_APC]
extension=php_apc.dll
```

to `php.ini`. restarting Apache fails. trying to execute `php` in cmd results in an error saying php5.dll is missing. but i doubt so. removing the 2 lines from php.ini fixes the error. how can i install apc then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i finally managed to install apc with the help from [here](http://www.rawseo.com/news/2009/06/09/how-to-install-alternative-php-cache/). i installed on IIS7

added to end of `php.ini`

```
[PHP_APC]
extension=php_apc.dll

apc.shm_segments=1
apc.optimization=0
apc.shm_size=128
apc.ttl=7200
apc.user_ttl=7200
apc.num_files_hint=1024
apc.mmap_file_mask=/tmp/apc.XXXXXX
apc.enable_cli=1
```

tho i got no idea what the configuration does